# "Add up to total" vs "add to total"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

### !

There is a possible problem with [this](http://www.infoplease.com/us/census/data/demographic.html):

> The six numbers may ***add to*** more than the total population and the six percentages may ***add to*** more than 100 percent because individuals may report more than one race.

Shouldn't it be ***add UP to***?

Comment: Yes, because as it is, it really means the number will pile *on top of* existing values. In this context, that sense of *add to* (thereby increasing) does not make sense. What is intended is *together amount to*, which is *add **up** to*. This is only in the semantic sense. Grammar-wise the expressions are still valid, though.

Comment: I think "equal" could replace both instances and suffice.

Comment: In my opinion, both are OK.  The numbers add up to 100.  The numbers add to 100.  Now, with *multiply* I would just say "The numbers multiply to 100" and not "multiply up".

Answer (score 4):

Grammar isn't really the issue here. It's both pedantic and wrong to suppose numbers can only be *"added **to**"* other numbers, or *"add **up** to"* a total. It's true that in OP's context, *"up"* would normally be included - for example, [the numbers add **up** to {some total X}](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22the%20numbers%20add%20up%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) is about four times more common than [the numbers add to X](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22numbers%20add%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20numbers%20add%20to%22&oq=%22the%20numbers%20add%20to%22&gs_l=serp.3...13451.14034.2.14313.3.3.0.0.0.0.134.257.2j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.zFygb5G26GU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1150&bih=867), but that's just idiomatic preference. Consider...

> He [can add two and two and](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22can%20add%20two%20and%20two%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22can%20add%20two%20and%20two%20and%22&oq=%22can%20add%20two%20and%20two%20and%22&gs_l=serp.3...7243.8683.0.9061.5.5.0.0.0.0.135.406.4j1.5.0...0.0...1c.1.lAwZIMBNavY&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1150&bih=867) get five. *(about 2000 instances in Google Books)*
>
> He [can add **up** two and two and](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22can%20add%20two%20and%20two%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22can%20add%20up%20two%20and%20two%20and%22&hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&ei=c3CzUKvrDuva0QXliIDYDA&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1150&bih=867) get five. *(17 instances)*

OP might be happier if the word **sum** were used instead - I assume he has no problem with numbers that *sum to a total* (but there's nothing wrong with numbers that [sum **up** to X](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22numbers%20add%20to%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22that%20sum%20up%20to%22&oq=%22that%20sum%20up%20to%22&gs_l=serp.3...10671.12519.5.12974.11.11.0.0.0.2.195.869.9j2.11.0...0.0...1c.1.QC1r3SpKs4s&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=65087f4ec2c01d51&bpcl=38897761&biw=1150&bih=867) either).

Answer (score 3):

Normally, people say "add to" when they mean to add to an existing or running total, and "add up to" when they mean to calculate a sum from scratch.

"Add the transaction amount to the balance."

"Add up the transaction amounts to calculate the balance."

In the example you give, the meaning is clear, so I wouldn't call it wrong. But it's unconventional. Yes, most English-speakers would write, "The six numbers may add UP to more than the total ..."